# Page Not found error, even routes are given angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm developing Admin panel and user panel. Admin panel was working fine and the code was written in `ExpressJs`. Now i wanted to design my User panel in `AngularJs`. i created HTML pages and `app.js` page.

```
use strict;

angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/profile/:userId', {
        templateUrl: 'profile.html',
        controller: 'profileController'
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
    }])
    .controller('profileController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
        $scope.params = $routeParams;
        $http.get('json_files/record_'+$scope.params.userId+'.json').success(function(response) {
        $scope.details = response;
       });    
    })
    .controller('homeController', function() {

    });
```

This is my app.js file.

Below is my profile.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="http://localhost:8000/">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div ng-controller="profileController">
            <table>
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <td>CategoryID</td>
                       <td>CategoryName</td>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  <tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
                      <td>{{category.CategoryID}}</td>
                    <td>{{category.CategoryName}}</td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
             </table>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the error as below whenever i'm trying to access the page as http://localhost:8000/profile/1

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /profile was not found on this server.

Don't know whats going wrong... or where I did mistake... 
Kindly suggest anything.

Comment: does other routes are working

Comment: could you please put your code in http://plnkr.co/

Comment: None of the routes are working, able to access direct home.html in tthe URl but not like /home

Comment: @Sam, sorry but its a company project and I'm not suppose give the files.  what ever i have shown the post.

Comment: @SharanDeSilva I'm not able to find what the issue is because it seems to be perfect.... this project is combination of AngularJs and ExpressJs, folders are different for Admin code done in expressjs and angularjs folders are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `ng-view` in your index page. All your routes will be replaced by  this tag.

refer this link : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div ng-view></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```
<div> Home page

    <a href="#/profile/1" >Go to Profile page</a>

</div>
```

**profile.html**

```
<div> Profile page

    <a href="#/home" >Go to Home page</a>

<div>
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/profile/:userId', {
            templateUrl: 'profile.html',
            controller: 'profileController'
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });

    }])

    .controller('profileController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
        $scope.params = $routeParams;
        /*$http.get('json_files/record_' + $scope.params.userId + '.json').success(function(response) {
            $scope.details = response;
        });*/
    })

        .controller('homeCtrl', function() {})
        .controller('profileController', function() {})

})();
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using mottie keyboard https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard. i added all the js files and css files in index.html and not to access keyboard in home.html. all scripts are working fine. Can you please help me out in this issue.

Comment: If you create a plunker for your issue that will be easy to debug :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your project root path first, then '#' and than the route.

Check https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09 for more details.

Comment: tired that as well but didn't worked for me. Any other solution.. please...

Comment: Also notice that the 'ngView' is missing in your code.

Comment: Thank You, I added still same 404 error is coming. any other... please

Comment: As a test you can try injecting $location to your controller and calling  `$location.path('/profile/1');`